# Saving document and its object id for referencing in other documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

In a `Node.js` App with `Mongodb`/`Mongoose`. i have two collections. `Users` and `Books`. My question is: when a user saves a book i have to save it in the `Books` collection and its object id inside `Users` collection for referencing. Two save operation for one user input.

Is this correct way? is this `Mongodb` standard? in a relation based database system its a wrong architecture but in the lack of Join in `Mongodb` what should i do? if i have a large database should i save current books id inside each of related collections?

I know that i can has books embedded into each user document but it has own problems.

Im confused. what should i do?

Comment: you should make a key on Book model 'author' where you save the User that post the book _ID

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MySQL "join" in MongoDB with Mongoose. It is not the MongoDB standard but it makes developing in MongoDB sometimes a lot easier. Below are two simple example schema's.

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type String
    },
    author: {
        type: String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    books: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Book'
    }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In the last schema there is a "books" property with a reference to books. You can store Strings of Object id's inside the array (not as an object). If you want, you can also store Object id's instead of Strings. Below is an example schema for a user:

```
{
    username: "Fcoder",
    books: ["550adf3899fbe92a168d3051", "550adf3899fbe92a168d3052"]
}
```

When querying your MongoDB database, you can [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the data. Your query will look like this:

```
User.find({}).populate('books').exec(function(err, data) {
    // callback
});
```

Inside data, you will find something like this:

```
{
    username: "Fcoder",
    books: [{
        _id: ObjectId("550adf3899fbe92a168d3051"),
        title 'Some title 1',
        author: 'Some author 1'
    }, {
        _id: ObjectId("550adf3899fbe92a168d3052"),
        title 'Some title 2',
        author: 'Some author 2'
    }
}
```